# What happened to the /stats method?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I can't find the `/stats` method in the [new usage documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage).

A quick run of `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/stats` reveals that the method is still there. However, it is not documented.

Comment: also `/stats` still says the API is on version 1.0

Comment: @Jonathan: You're right! I didn't notice that.

Comment: Also, the `/posts/{id}/comment` method is missing from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops, missed that one.

The `/posts/{id}/comment` documentation isn't missing, but it is under the **Comments** header which may make it easy to miss.

Returning "1.0" for the API version is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), for compatibility purposes.

It was a mistake to even add that field (made sense in the beta, makes no sense with a released API), consider it deprecated.